# How to add an entity-specific listener in Symfony2 that has access to container

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

In a Symfony2 application, I have an entity that needs to be populated on pre-persist with various context properties (like user id, what page it was called from, etc.)

I figured that to do this, I need to add a doctrine event listener that has access to "service_container", and the best way to give such access is to pass "service_container" as an argument to this listener.

I have a specific entity that I want to listen to, and I do not want to trigger the listener to events with any other entity.

We can add an entity-specific listener, documentation is found here:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners
 - but this does not provide example of how to pass an argument (I use PHP annotations to declare the listener).

I also tried to use JMSDiExtraBundle annotations, like in the example below:
http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSDiExtraBundle/master/annotations#doctrinelistener-or-doctrinemongodblistener
 - but this way requires to declare the listener as non-entity-specific

Is there any way to make a listener for one entity only, and have it have access to container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways similar to doctrine docs through dependency injection:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EntityListener;

use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;

class UserListener {

    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function postPersist(User $user, LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $logger = $this->logger;

        $logger->info('Event triggered');

        //Do something
    }
}
```

---

```
services:
  user.listener:
      class: AppBundle\EntityListener\UserListener
      arguments: [@logger]
      tags:
          - { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener }
```

---

And dont forget add listener to entity mapping:

```
AppBundle\Entity\User:
    type: entity
    table: null
    repositoryClass: AppBundle\Entity\UserRepository
    entityListeners:
        AppBundle\EntityListener\UserListener: ~
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simply check entity type from the event. If you check type inside or outside the subscriber, it has the same performance cost. And simple type condition is fast enough.

```
namespace App\Modules\CoreModule\EventSubscriber;

use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Events;


class SetCountryToTaxSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [Events::prePersist];
    }


    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $lifecycleEventArgs)
    {
        $entity = $lifecycleEventArgs->getEntity();
        if ( ! $entity instanceof Tax) {
            return;
        }

        $entity->setCountry('myCountry');
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's just what I did. I guess this is the simplest way to go. And if performance cost is the same, this is probably also the best way to go.